# How to delete music album from iPhone but not from any other devices nor from iCloud

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

The fact I have to ask this question on here is testament to the utterly terrible user interface Apples these days seem to endorse. I know how to remove 1 track from the iPhone but still keep it in iCloud, but how do I remove a whole album from my iPhone but keep it on my other Apple devices and iCloud? I couldn't find a way either by trying or searching around. The only option seems to be to "Delete from Library", which I do not want to do.

**EDIT**

I tried to look at my iTunes settings, but the relevant settings page is almost empty, see screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Via iTunes

When you sync your iPhone with your main iTunes on a desktop computer, you can simply untick the undesired song/album/artist and hit sync, and it will disappear from your iPhone.

[image]

<sup>Image from [HowToISolve](https://www.howtoisolve.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/sync-apple-music-playlist-to-iPhone.jpg)</sup>

In this example, ticking Ke$ha will include it, and unticking will exclude it from your phone iTunes library.

### 2. Directly on your iPhone

Go to `Settings > General > iPhone Storage > Music > Edit` to delete artists, or `... > Music > Song > Edit` to delete songs locally on your iPhone.

[image]

<sup>Image from my iPhone</sup>

Be aware that those files will be included should you sync your phone again.

Comment: My iTunes does not look like your screen shot. It only has one tick box that says "Sync voice memos".

Comment: @Ray But how do you get music onto your phone then? Only via iCloud downloads? Then use option #2

Comment: To be honest, I don't remember clearly. I seem to remember something like the screenshot you have, but for some reason, that options page is now nearly empty, and doesn't look like the one you have now.

Comment: Please see added screenshot. Is it because "iCloud Music Library is On"?